# How to get a list of all projections that are currently available in QGIS via the PyQGIS-API

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis

i'm building a QGIS-Plugin and i want the user to choose a CRS out of a combobox in which the coordinates he would enter into some textfields are represented, so these can be converted into another projection.

Is it possible to get a list of all the currently available projections via the PyQGIS-API?

I'm searching the QGIS-API right now, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The projections available in Qgis are stored in a sqlite database called srs.db, found in apps/qgins/resources. The data is stored in the `tbl_srs` table.

For a python approach, you can look into the transformation tools plugin.
`selectCrsDlg.py` should have the data you want.